# Swift のライブラリMessageKitについて

Tags: swift, ios, swift4

チャットUIを作るためにMessageKitを利用して開発しようとしているのですが、
下にあるように公式のサンプルと同じくmessagesDataSourceにselfを入れようとしても、
Cannot assign value of type "ViewController" to type "MessagesDataSource"
と表示されて設定できません。
問題点が分かる方がいれば、教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

import UIKit
import MessageKit

class ViewController: MessagesViewController {

```
var messages: [Message] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私はMessageKitは使ったことがないんですが、"MessageKit 使い方"で見つかった記事と、[ソースコード](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit)によると、その行は`ViewController`を`MessagesDataSource`に適合させない限りコンパイルできません。

「公式のサンプル」がなんのことを指しているのか、はっきりとはわからないのですが、上記GitHubのExampleのコードを見ても、他のネット上の記事でも次のような`extension`が定義されているはずです。

```
extension ViewController: MessagesDataSource {
   func currentSender() -> Sender {
      return ... //アプリのユーザの情報を`Sender`型で返す
   }

   func numberOfSections(in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> Int {
      return messages.count
    }

   func messageForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> MessageType {
      return messages[indexPath.section]
    }
}
```

`ViewController`と同じソースファイルの最後に、上記のような`extension`を追加してみてください。`MessagesDataSource`プロトコルには他のメソッドもいくつか定義されていますが、どれもデフォルト実装が与えられているので、最低限上記3つのメソッドを実装すれば`MessagesDataSource`に適合させられます。(`func currentSender() -> Sender`の実装方法はあなたのアプリがユーザ情報をどのように保持するかによって変わります。動作確認用のお試し実装なら、上記のキーワードで見つかる記事中などから見つかると思います。)

もちろん、他のメソッドも実装することにより、いろんな部分をカスタマイズできるようになっています。

他にも

```
    messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
    messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self
    messagesCollectionView.messageCellDelegate = self
    messageInputBar.delegate = self
```

辺りのコードを書かれることになるんだろうと思いますが、そのそれぞれで別々のプロトコルに適合させておかないとエラーになります。

Swiftの場合、必須のプロトコル適合が`class`定義から離れた場所に書けてしまうのでわかりにくいんですが、プロトコルに適合させるための`extension`抜きでは、体験されたように`class`定義本体がコンパイル出来なくなったりします、お気をつけ下さい。とりあえずご質問のエラーは上記の`extension`を追加すれば出なくなるはずです。

Comment: 分かりやすく、丁寧なご回答ありがとうございました。